# Connecting Arduino Uno with Ethernet shield to parse.com database

Tags: parse-platform, arduino-uno

Hey I'm new to Arduino programming, I was wondering how i can connect my device to store data to parse.com.

I know the REST API Key but not sure one what to do. Any help would be appreciated, and if possible can you provide source code or examples.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload data to Parse.com using Arduino and GSM shield and Parse REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375847/upload-data-to-parse-com-using-arduino-and-gsm-shield-and-parse-rest-api)

Comment: thats for a GSM shield mine is just an ethernet shield.

Comment: It doesn't matter - the IP stack is independent of the shield, and the Arduino isn't capable of https/ssl

Comment: So this can't be done?

Comment: Not with pure Arduino - you need a non-SSL server somewhere to proxy the message to parse.com

Comment: do you know of any examples that can help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now possible. An Arduino Uno + ethernet shied still can't make HTTP requests, and parse.com still needs HTTPs, but Temboo makes it possible. Here's what you need to do:

1. Create an account at [Temboo.com](https://www.temboo.com)
2. Go to the [Parse bundle](https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Parse/)
3. Find the Choreo you're interested in e.g., UploadFile, and test it out from the Temboo website
4. Turn on IoT Mode, set up your shield, and use the generated Arduino sketch code to connect your board to Parse.

Here's a blog post about Temboo's Iot Mode - the feature makes all of this possible:

http://blog.temboo.com/post/88573872731/flip-the-switch-and-get-going

I hope this helps.